# Using session objects from parent class in component

Tags: session, object, components, tapestry

During my battle with tapestry 5 I created some setup which does not work, and I don't know why. I found few work-arounds, but still I would like to know why initial idea failed.

I have parent abstract page class with application-wide auth procedure:

```
public abstract class AuthPage {
    @SessionState
    protected UserAuth user;


    public Object onActivate(){
        if(user==null)
            return LoginForm.class;
        else if(user.getLoggedIn().equals(Boolean.FALSE))
            return LoginForm.class;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then I have index page class, using auth class as aprent:

```
public class Index extends AuthPage
{

}
```

This part works smoohtly - when user SSO is initialized then I got Index content, otherwise it goes to LoginForm. Now the problematic part - Index uses a layout component which takes care of showing personalized header and menu. Its logic looks like that:

```
public class Layout extends AuthPage
{  
    @Property
    private Boolean loggedIn;

    @Property
    private String userName;

    @SetupRender
    public boolean checkNames(){
        if(user==null){
            loggedIn = false;
            userName = "unlogged";
        }
        else if(user.getLoggedIn().equals(Boolean.FALSE)){
            loggedIn=false;
            userName = "unlogged";
        }
        else{
            loggedIn = true;
            userName = this.user.getUsername();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The idea was simple - session object user from AuthPage should be available in Layout, and used on setup-render stage to get user name and rising the flag for rendering menu etc. From my point of view everything should work, but in practice Layout class didn't get user object from session (despite that it was initialized for sure, because Index renders its content).

So my question is - why Layout class don't see UserAuth object stored in session, but gets it as null instead?

****************** little update:

I've refactore layout to that shape:

```
public class Layout
{
    @SessionState
    protected UserAuth user;

    @Property
    private Boolean loggedIn;

    @Property
    private String userName;

    @SetupRender
    public boolean checkNames(){
        if(user==null){
             loggedIn = false;
             userName = "unlogged";
        }
        else if(user.getLoggedIn().equals(Boolean.FALSE)){
             loggedIn=false;
             userName = "unlogged";
        }
        else{
             loggedIn = true;
             userName = this.user.getUsername();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and it works as I want - Layout (executet from Index page as component) takes user attribute from session, performs checkNames and sets up all properties properly. For me there is no technical difference between initial and second implementation, but somehow when user is defined in parent class is always set to null (no matter what is stored in session). The question is - why it works that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem! Answer is a little bit unexpected for me, but well - everything seems to work fine now. The trick is the way I was refering to the user attribue ot AuthPage class. I used

```
this.user
```

to refere to it from child classes. It turned out that I've got it as null everywhere, even in pages (I had an impression that it worked correctly in Index page, but in fact it was just used in AuthPage class). The solution was to refere by:

```
super.user
```

When I switched to such referencing style suddenly every page and component started to work properly and got correct values from session. I'll just take it as it is, but if someone knows why it works that way and no other - I'll appreciate sharing this knowledge with me.

Comment: Is it only "this.user" that fails? Or does "user" fail too? Tapestry uses byte code manipulation to switch all instance field references to getters. Looks like it might have missed this

Comment: Both "this.user" and "user" was failing.

Comment: Can you try setting [tapestry.production-mode](http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-tapestry.productionmode) to false and try again? I think it should work in development mode. It helps file a better jira issue if we understand the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to test it out in near future and post results if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

Layout is a component, not a page, and onActivate() is page event which won't be fired when the Layout component renders. For a component (Layout) to extend a page (AuthPage) does not make sense. I'm surprised that Tapestry allows it to tell the truth.

On another note, Tapestry has so many features (including filters, class transformations and mixins) that inheritance is almost always not required. Although quite complex, you might find the diagram at the bottom of [this page](http://tapestry.apache.org/request-processing.html) useful. In particular you may be interested in the ComponentRequestFilters and PageRenderRequestFilters.

Here's a couple of options for securing pages:

1. [Howard Lewis Ship's blog](http://tapestryjava.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/securing-tapestry-pages-with.html) - Howard is the creator of Tapestry
2. [Tynamo tapestry security](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security+guide)

Comment: It's not exaclty like that. I know the Layout is not a page, and I am not counting on it to run onActivate method from AuthPage. I just want it to have UserAuth session object (as extension of AuthPage should have). Everything what Layout should do is included in Layout.checkNames(), but it works like the user attribute from parent class is detached from session. Other way, e.g. when UserAuth object is explicitly defined in Layout class (and annotated as SSO) it is initilized from session properly. I just don't understand why it's not working when UserAuth object is defined in parent class.

Comment: Is AuthPage in the ```basepackage.pages.*``` package? If it is, it might be confusing tapestry. A component should never extend a page.

Comment: It's not that problem. I've moved AuthPage all around (to root package of project, to package external to pages and components and even I've put it to same package as Layout) but outcome was the same - session object from AuthPage initialized properly for Index page and null for Layout component.

Comment: You say you put it into components and into same package a layout. What package is layout in? I'm assuming it's in components (or a subpackage of components).

Comment: Yes it is. Regarding the structure my project is simple and correct (works, and so on). Index page is in pages, Layout component in components and AuthPage superclass in Pages (but also was in other packages and didn't work too). I believe the whole problem is more about handling parental class attributes by components (at least regarding session storage) than on project structure.

Comment: Sounds like you've found a bug. Have you tried a private field in the superclass and a getter() instead of protected? And please, NEVER have a component extend a page.

Comment: Well, it seems more and more like a bug. I've created an abstract class similar to AuthPage, placed it in components package and made Layout extend it. Layout after initialization didn't get user attribute, as in all other cases. It seems that tapestry is not initilizing session state objects existing in parent classes of components which are in use. Could you (or someone) check such case as I described and confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

What version of tapestry are you using? In tapestry 5.3.1 and earlier, instance variables must be private. Only version 5.3.2+ supports protected and package private.

http://tapestry.apache.org/page-and-component-classes-faq.html#PageAndComponentClassesFAQ-Whydomyinstancevariableshavetobeprivate%3F

Comment: I have Tapestry 5.3.2 so it shouldn't be that case.